# git-gui clone: What is the difference of each "Clone Type"?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-gui

Using the standard `git-gui` (v 0.20.GITGUI), there are three "Clone type"  options, when you want to clone a repository:

- Standard
- Full Copy
- Shared

[image: Git-Gui clone options]

What is the difference between these three types?
Is this a `git-gui` thing, or is there a command line equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messages come from [commit ab08b36, gitgui-0.9.0, Sept. 2007](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab08b3630414dfb867825c4a5828438e1c69199d) (ten years ago!), by [Shawn O. Pearce (`spearce`)](https://github.com/spearce)

Shawn commented at the time:

> If the source repository is on the local disk we try to use a
>   hardlink to connect the objects into the new clone as this can
>   be many times faster than copying the objects or packing them and
>   passing the data through a pipe to index-pack.
>   **Unlike `git-clone`, we stick to pure Tcl** [file link -hard] operation thus avoiding the need to fork a cpio process to setup the hardlinks.
>
> If hardlinks do not appear to be supported (e.g. filesystem doesn't allow them or we are crossing filesystem boundaries) we use file copying instead.

So there is no *exact* git clone equivalent.
But shared and hardlink applies only for cloning local repos and are equivalent to [`git clone -l` and `git clone --shared`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_options).
Full will copy all pack files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped a lot in understanding git-gui.

(If anyone comes across this question: I still recommend using the git bash (which is included in the windows intstallation), or cygwin.)